# Where can I find a copy of Starbase Jeff?

Tags: starbase-jeff

One of my favorite games is a now out-of-print game from Cheapass games called Starbase Jeff.  I've been looking for a copy of it for years and haven't had any luck.  Sadly, the game wasn't designed by James Ernest but another game designer, so I doubt it will eventually join the other fine games that he has put out for free on the cheapass site.

**Does anyone know where I could get a copy of the game?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the apparent passing of the [designer](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/86472/item/1945427#item1945427), my guess is that the copyright would revert to his estate (probably his wife). This isn't the time or place to be asking her to release it to the public domain though.

It appears that at least two places have the out of print game for sale, although I cannot vouch for the authenticity of the products they are selling.

[BGG Marketplace](http://boardgamegeek.com/geekstore.php3?action=viewitem&itemid=341233)

[Noble Knight](http://www.nobleknight.com/ProductDetailSearch.asp_Q_ProductID_E_7423_A_InventoryID_E_2147738913) this appears to be a sale house middleman like CardShark.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Starbase Jeff is [available for free](http://cheapass.com/free-games/starbase-jeff/) on the Cheapass Games website. You'll have to print it out yourself but that sort of thing isn't super complicated and might be easier than locating a copy of the original version.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the boardgamegeek.com marketplace, auctions or auction forum periodically. that would be your best bet.  I actually have a copy that I am going to list on the auction forum some time in the next few weeks (just depends on when I get everything listed and ready to go). I am hippyhillary on the geek.